# Find how many cores are being used by a c# application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I can get total no of processors by the code:

```
Environment.ProcessorCount
```

How to find out how many processors are being used by a c# console application.
For example, if I have total 4 processors then is my application is using all the processors or less.

Comment: Well this is totally dynamic and can change from moment to moment.

Comment: Open [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and check.

Comment: if your not explicity have threading code then the answer is presumably all processor are used sometime but never more than one at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to get a precise answer without using specific performance monitoring tools, and it does vary moment to moment.

I'd suggest using Perfmon while running your application as a starting point for your analysis.  If you're using certain versions of Visual Studio, you can also try Analyze | Performance Profiler.

If you want a quick and dirty - run your application and look in debugger or task manager.  If you've got a 4 core/thread processor, you'd expect to see around max 25% of your CPU being used if you're only utilising a single thread with your code.

Look into concepts such as Async/Await and Task Parallel Library if you want better utilise the available processing power.